# Magento Cronjob error also Heartbeat not found

Tags: scheduled-tasks, magento-1.9, cron-task

when i run the Tasks :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/soulexhi/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/soulexhi/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default
```

As per Cron Scheduler tells me to i am getting this error message via Email
HELP!!

```
Content-type: text/html; 

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(/abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/soulexhi/public_html/shell/scheduler.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/abstract.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/soulexhi/public_html/shell/scheduler.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
```

At the beginning of the file 'magento_root/shell/scheduler.php' there is a require_once that I changed to the following to:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))
        require_once dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'abstract.php';
else
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'abstract.php';
```

but it did not work. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It was the PHP version of Cron Jobs.

The PHP version was set correctly for the site which is why it was working; however Cron Jobs was running at server native PHP 5.3 which is why I was getting the errors only when running Cron. I updated to version 5.5.

Changed Cron command:

```
php /home/mydomainname/public_html/cron.php
to
php55 /home/mydomainname/public_html/cron.php
```

in cron.php

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

After this line, add:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```